# Tab to view files in directly?

Tags: command-line

Is it possible to press tab or some other operator to view the available files in a given directory path? For example:

[image]

For example, in the unix shell I can do something like `[tab]` to get:

[image]

After trial-and-erring a bit, it seems like `:e` is the command I want to use instead of `:o` ? Is `:e` basically like "open with tab-complete" ?

Comment: `:h 'wildmenu'`

Comment: I think you're looking for `<c-d>`. Indeed, it does not work with `:o`, you'll need `:e`.

Answer (score 1):

Open mode (from the `:open` command) is a bit of a legacy command:

```
                            *:o* *:op* *:open*
:[range]o[pen]          Works like |:visual|: end Ex mode.
                {Vi: start editing in open mode}

:[range]o[pen] /pattern/    As above, additionally move the cursor to the
                column where "pattern" matches in the cursor
                line.

Vim does not support open mode, since it's not really useful.  For those
situations where ":open" would start open mode Vim will leave Ex mode, which
allows executing the same commands, but updates the whole screen instead of
only one line.
```

You want to use `:edit` instead to, well, edit a file. By default, you should be able to use `:help cmdline-completion`, including <kbd>tab</kbd>, to complete filenames. This works for `:split`, `:vsplit` , and `:tabedit`, too, as these are the standard "edit a file" commands.

Comment: Having said that, `:tag`-related commands and `:find`- or `'path'`-related commands make my file-navigation much faster; rather than tab-completing to find what I want, I just jump directly to it